Can't sign into my github account in vscode on arch linux
I have recently installed arch linux.
I installed vscode using yay -S visual-studio-code-bin.

Now when I open the vscode app. 

When i click on backup and sync and the sign in, the app just stops prompting me to force quit.
I tried googling but no answer


the app just stops prompting me to force quit
What do you mean ? Also, try launching the app from a terminal, with --verbose to get more information.


It forces me to force quit. I meant to say that the app stops responding and the force quit or wait message box pops up.

If I can help just join with the use of the localhost, it will automatically offers you, when you try to signing in the source control. it will open your prefered browser, than join to your github account normally, then inside vscode cancel it and then there will be an option to setup a local server click on it and it should work
If the problem persist, write me email: hons.lonzo@gmail.com or on discord: nikolajk97
If you choose to write email write to subject Log In VSCODE.
I hope it will work

i forgot install:
sudo pacman -S gnome-keyring
systemctl --user enable --now gnome-keyring-daemon.service

Make sure to [edit] new details into answers instead of posting them as comments.
